# How to do number formatting to 1 decimal point in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have  a SSRS report with full of number fields. I would like to have that to be displayed as in one decimal. i tried to use F1. it gives me only one decimal points in html rendering, but in excel exported version it shows 2 decimal points. 
How can i have just one decimal point both ecxel and html rendering.

Please comment.
Thanks in advance
San

Answer (score 19):

Use **N1** as your Format Property setting. **N** denotes Numeric formatting, the **1** denotes the number of decimal places, so **N2** would give you 102.02, for example. This should carry to excel as it is rendered in html.

Alternatively, you could use the format code #,##0.00, which will give you the thousands separator and two decimal places. '#' indicates optional characters, whilst '0' indicates mandatory characters (nulls will be replaced by '0.00').

Answer (score 1):

in 2012 version:  FormatNumber(Fields!col.Value,2)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the text box that contains the value you would like manipulate, select TEXT BOX PROPERTIES.  Navigate to the Number tab, select Number and the # of Decimal places you want the box to allow for.