# use expression to set the format property of a textbox in an rdlc report

Tags: rdlc

I am working with rdlc reports. I want to set the format property of values displayed by a table row in my report to so as it could be $ sign if some condition is true and not to show the $ sing if thecondition is false. I know that if I want the row to show values with the $ sign mark I just have to write C on the format property after selecting the row cell in design. Is there a way I could make this happen using an expression in the properties in the Format property. Currently all I can come up with is the expression I have written below which doesn't work as it is displayed instead of the value I am getting from the database when the report is  when the report is run

```
iif(fields!TableColumn.value="Percent", D,C)
```

I have used D as D represents decimal and C for currency as these are the two formats I want displayed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In .Format property you have to set something like this:

```
=IIf(Fields!YourColumn.Value = "Percent", "f", "c")
```

Note that I use "f" instead of decimal because I usually use this parameter.

If you want to format your cell as decimal you can consider this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007404/how-to-do-number-formatting-to-1-decimal-point-in-ssrs) on stackoverflow.